# Let $(L,\leq)$ a bounded lattice. Let $(L',\leq)$ a sublattice of $L$. Is $L'$ bounded too?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $(L,\leq)$ a bounded lattice. Let $(L',\leq)$ a sublattice of $L$. Is $L'$ bounded too? I'd say $L'$ is bounded too, since given two elements $a \in L'$ and $b \in L'$, there is $c \in L'$ such that $c \leq a$ and $c \leq b$, so going all the way down there must be an element $m \in L'$ such that $m \leq x$ for every $x \in L'$.

But I can't think of a proof of this nor a counter example to prove the opposite. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Thank you I'll edit it right away.

Comment: What signature does your bounded lattice have?

Comment: $[0, 1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded lattice but $(0, 1)$ is not

Comment: @AlvinL I don't think that's relevant. We are talking about sublattices here, not substructures of bounded lattices.

Comment: @AlvinL I'm not sure I'm familiar with the concept of signature.

Comment: @leafy111 This is something that comes up when talking about generalization of the concept of a structure (or more like, formalization of it). For example, in model theory or universal algebra. As I said, I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you, I'm convinced by your response. I was stuck at looking for a discrete example.